# Trac - Get date of last commit of a specific repository file in wiki page

Tags: date, wiki, commit, hyperlink, trac

I'm using Trac to manage my projects. Some guys have to take a regular look to my wiki pages to watch changes in a special file. Therefore I have a link on my wikipage. Something link this:

```
[source:MyRepository/trunk/subfolder/file.pdf@head The file to read]
```

What I would like to have is the following output:

---

The file to read (last commited: 11/01/15 at 08:52am)

---

Any ideas how to manage that in trac wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have to write a small plugin for that, something like the following:

```
from genshi.builder import tag

from trac.util.datefmt import format_datetime
from trac.util.translation import _
from trac.versioncontrol.api import RepositoryManager
from trac.wiki.api import parse_args
from trac.wiki.macros import WikiMacroBase


class SourceMacro(WikiMacroBase):
    def expand_macro(self, formatter, name, content):
        args, kwargs = parse_args(content)
        path = args[0]
        label = kwargs.get('label', path)
        rm = RepositoryManager(self.env)
        reponame, repos, path = rm.get_repository_by_path(path)
        node = repos.get_node(path)
        href = formatter.href.browser(reponame or None, path)
        return tag(tag.a(label, href=href),
                   _(' (last committed: %(date)s)',
                     date=format_datetime(node.last_modified)))
```

(For Trac 0.12 or later, error handling left as the dreaded exercise to the reader.)

Place this in a file file named `source_link.py` in the `plugins` directory of your Trac environment. Then you can reference your files with the following macro:

```
[[Source(MyRepository/trunk/subfolder/file.pdf)]]
```

or if you want a specific label:

```
[[Source(MyRepository/trunk/subfolder/file.pdf, label=The file to read)]]
```

Comment: How do you specify that a code block should be rendered as Python code?

Comment: WOW! thank you for the fast response... I'll try that and will report.